# MapView animateCamera doesn't work with Handler.postDelayed

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-handler

When I use this code:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                                new LatLng(latitude,longitude),
                                                TARGET_ZOOM_LEVEL)
                                        , CAMERA_ANIMATION_DURATION, null);
```

It works like expected, but when i use the same code in Handler.postDelayed it doesn't zoom good the latitude and longitude are outside of the visible region of the map

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.
                                        newLatLngZoom(
                                                new LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                                                TARGET_ZOOM_LEVEL)
                                        , CAMERA_ANIMATION_DURATION, null);
                            }
                        }, CAMERA_ANIMATION_DURATION);

                    }
```

Any help is welcome :) thanks in advance

Comment: there is no difference if you call it directly or as a Handler's callback...

Comment: it's my conviction but unfortunatly I dont know why I don't have the same behavior